# Ruby Hash transpose

Tags: ruby, hash, transpose

I have the following ruby hash:

```
 h = { i1: { q1: 1, q2:2 }, i2: { q1: 3, q2: 4} }
```

and I want to transpose it as follows:

```
{ q1: { i1: 1, i2: 3 }, q2: { i1: 2, i2: 4 } }
```

Now, I came up with a function that does what I want,
but I wonder if there is a more succinct/elegant way for the same thing?

My solution:

```
 ht = Hash.new{ |h,k| h[k] = {} }

 h.each_pair do |k,ih| 
   ih.each_pair{ |ik, iv| ht[ik][k] = iv }
 end
```

Comment: That is already very succint. Do you have a real world example of when you want to transform the hash like that?

Comment: I have basically the same data structure (just bigger) with indicators (i1, i2, ... ) and their values at some dates (q1, q2, q3, ....). I'm still not sure weather I should use here two dimensional array instead (actually I'm still evaluating both versions...)

Comment: If you often do this kind of juggling, you might find easier to use Sqlite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you prefer `inject`, you can write it as

```rb
h.inject({}) do |a, (k, v)|
  v.inject(a) do |a1, (k1, v1)|
    a1[k1] ||= {}
    a1[k1][k] = v1
    a1
  end
  a
end
```

Comment: Yes, it does the same, just with inject, although I think first way to do it is slightly more readable (In the real function I have to include few more lines of code like exception handling etc...)

Comment: Have you used a kind of minification library on this code block? It looks uglified :)